# Filtering points in GeoServer layer

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2

So, I have a GeoServer layer with point markers (POI) in several category such as ATMs, churches, government buildings, parks, etc.

Is there a way to filter this layer via URL parameters so I don't have to define a new layer for each category?

also, I am using openlayers-3 as the frontend interface.

To complete the question, I have a request URL like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gis_localhost/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=gis_localhost:table_location&styles=&bbox=95.282956,5.517893,95.374536,5.60221&width=768&height=707&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers
```

with the result similar to this:

[image]

where each of category is saved as `category` in postgis `table_location`.
Now I want to filter based on category, for example I want to use filter to only show police stations

Comment: openlayers 2 like the tag, or openlayers 3 like the question?

Comment: This is what WFS CQL/ECQL queries do. Have you looked at the filter options in http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/syntax.html ?

Comment: CMIIW, as long as my understanding, what CQL do in geoserver is creating a query from available layer, and save it as new layer. so, if I have 20 categories, it will create 20 new layers that I can use later. What I am asking is, is there a way to filter from Url without defining a new layer. I read the documentation, but all of example there is confusing for a beginner like me and does not fit to my case.

Comment: You don't need to create a layer, and normally wouldn't. You can pass the filter as a vendor argument in the WMS URL, or as the `filter` in WFS. If you show an example of your URL, and the filter you want to use, I might have a chance to provide an answer.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: The answer below has how to do this for WMS, but a WFS query with client side styling would probably be better.

Comment: right, I will take my time to swallow this whole. thank you for the response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CQL_FILTER is documented in http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html.

Make a test request without CQL_FILTER

http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=topp:states&styles=&bbox=-124.73142200000001,24.955967,-66.969849,49.371735&width=768&height=330&srs=EPSG:4326&format=image/png

[image]

Make a new request with CQL_FILTER

http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=topp:states&styles=&bbox=-124.73142200000001,24.955967,-66.969849,49.371735&width=768&height=330&srs=EPSG:4326&format=image/png&CQL_FILTER=STATE_NAME=%27Texas%27

[image]

All you need to do is to make sure that your OpenLayers application adds a CQL_FILTER that fulfills your needs.

Comment: I see... I can directly input cql in preview and see the difference in requested URL. thank you :)